# Local variable value is not used in recursion

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

Here is my snippet:

```
core = client.CoreV1Api()
apps = client.AppsV1Api()

def get_pod_parent(resource, tmp):
    if resource.metadata.owner_references:
        parent = eval(f"apps.read_namespaced_{re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', resource.metadata.owner_references[0].kind).lower()}")(
            resource.metadata.owner_references[0].name,
            resource.metadata.namespace

        )
        get_pod_parent(parent, tmp)
    else:
        #print(resource)  it prints the resource which I need to take
        tmp = resource #Local variable 'tmp' value is not used 



pod = core.read_namespaced_pod('test_name', 'test_namespace')
last_parent = None
test = get_pod_parent(pod, last_parent)
print(last_parent) # It prints None
```

Why does it print `None`? I can't understand! I need to store the resource when it gets into the else. The resource is there, but I cant store it somehow. Is there someone who can explain what is going on and how can I take the needed resource outside of the function?

Comment: This question is not at all related to recursion. Just to argument passing. You could have used this minimal example: `def f(x): x=12` `x=1; f(x); print(x)` and see that it prints `1` not `12`.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses pass by value in this case therefore when you pass the variable last_parent it passes the value of the variable and any modification won't effect last_parent. What you probably want to do is write

```
return resource
```

Then when you call the function at the bottom will contain the value of resource when the function has run so if you print(test) you'll get what you need.

HOWEVER if you want the function to keep running after you have assigned it look it generators (using yield instead of return)

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried but it prints `None` because it is recursion and the always return `None`

Comment: If you are trying to get the data back up the recursion stack frames to the original variable, you will have to pass the data back up so to speak to when you run the function recursively. return it. So return get_pod_parent(...)

Comment: @htodev  That is another (very classical, and very "duplicate") question about recursion, totally unrelated to your first question: you need to return (and aggregate, maybe, depending on the problem) the values of recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

@chrslg You are right! I forgot that we are passing the values of arguments, not their references. So that is why I change the things a little bit in order to take the needed data.

```
def get_pod_parent(resource, store):
if resource.metadata.owner_references:
    parent = eval(
        f"apps.read_namespaced_{re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', resource.metadata.owner_references[0].kind).lower()}")(
        resource.metadata.owner_references[0].name,
        resource.metadata.namespace

    )
    get_pod_parent(parent, store)
else:
    store.update({'name': resource.metadata.name, 'namespace': resource.metadata.name})
pod = core.read_namespaced_pod('test_name', 'test_namespace')
store = {}
get_pod_parent(pod, store)
print(store)
```

So now the data which I need is there stored in `store` var. Thank you